# Build MyTimer that have a flag while elapse

Tags: c#, timer

i want to build a timer class that inherits from System.Timers.Timer.

as so

```
Class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
   public bool IsRunning{ get; set;}
}
```

and while its elapse the flag will be true , and when the thread is over the falge will be false again. any idea ?

Comment: This might not be necessary. You'd need to try this (the documentation isn't specific about this point), but I think if you use a Timer with AutoReset = false, then `Enabled` behaves exactly like your `IsRunning` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled.aspx) property?

If the timer is NOT an AutoReset timer (i.e. it will fire exactly once), then if Timer.Enabled is true, then the timer IS running.  When the timer elapses and fires the Elapsed event, then Timer.Enabled will no longer be true.

If the timer IS an AutoReset timer (i.e. it will fire every time the interval elapses), then if Timer.Enabled is true, then the timer IS running.

I'm not sure what extra capability you are looking for with your proposed IsRunning property that is not already available via the Enabled property.

See the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) documentation.

If you want a timer that will tell you if the Elapsed event is currently running, then you could do something like this:

```
  public class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer
  {
    ElapsedEventHandler elapsed;

    public bool IsElapsedEventRunning { get; set; }

    //
    // Accept the ElapsedEventHandler in the constructor since the Elapsed property
    // is not virtual so it cannot be overridden.
    //
    public MyTimer(double interval, ElapsedEventHandler elapsed)
    {
      IsElapsedEventRunning = false;

      this.Interval = interval;

      // Save the ElapsedEventHandler
      this.elapsed = elapsed;

      // Set the base Timer's Elapsed event property to MY OWN ElapsedEventHandler
      Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    //
    // When base timer fires Elapsed event, my ElapsedEventHandler will be called.
    // Inside, set IsElapsedEventRunning = true, then call the user's event handler.
    // When finished, set IsElapsedEventRunning = false
    //
    void MyTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      //
      // Warning!  Not thread safe!  Not reentrant!
      //
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyTimer.IsElapsedEventRunning = {0}", IsElapsedEventRunning);

      IsElapsedEventRunning = true;

      // Is Invoke ok here or is BeginInvoke/EndInvoke required?
      elapsed.Invoke(sender, e);

      IsElapsedEventRunning = false;

      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyTimer.IsElapsedEventRunning = {0}", IsElapsedEventRunning);
    }

  }
```

Note that the ElapsedEventHandler (MyTimer_Elapsed) is not very robust (e.g. reentrancy is not even considered).  If the Elapsed event takes longer to process than the Interval, the Elapsed event will fire again.

There are examples in the Timer documentation that show how to implement more robust ElapsedEventHandlers.  That information might be applicable here.

Having said all of that, this seems like it is not a very good idea.  My guess is that this will be difficult to get to work correctly and reliably.

Comment: The enabled property is indicating that the timer can raise events not if currently the thread is running that is why.

Comment: Be careful with it, I'm not sure how safe it is!